# Dynamically create object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to dynamically create an array of objects.

The array will be called 'groups'. It will contain an unknown number of objects (these are the Group Names) which will be determined by the `ID` of an element. Each object will contain an unknown number of properties (these are the Group Properties), these will be determined by the inner text of a `div` and their value will be determined by the inner text of another `div`.

I know how to get each of these values using `.each()` and `.attr('ID')` and `.text()`. I just can't work out how to create the array of objects.

```
// Example HTML 
<div id="england">
    <div class="property">health</div>
    <div class="count">3</div>
    <div class="property">education</div>
    <div class="count">1</div>
    <div class="property">entertainment</div>
    <div class="count">12</div>
</div>
<div id="scotland">
    <div class="property">geography</div>
    <div class="count">5</div>
    <div class="property">history</div>
    <div class="count">2</div>
</div>
<div id="wales">
    <div class="property">illustration</div>
    <div class="count">4</div>
    <div class="property">business</div>
    <div class="count">6</div>
    <div class="property">fashion</div>
    <div class="count">3</div>
</div>
```

.

```
// Example JSON output of the 'groups' array
{  
    "england":{  
        "health":"3",
        "education":"1",
        "entertainment":"12"
    },
    "scotland":{  
        "geography":"5",
        "history":"2"
    },
    "wales":{  
        "illustration":"4",
        "business":"6",
        "fashion":"3"
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to create this from html post your html.

Comment: ... and if you want js output, your output should be in js.

Comment: I'll edit with some example HTML shortly.

Comment: Could you also show an example of what your array of object would look like, as the above doesn't not look like any Javascript array I know off..

Comment: You'll probably want to initialize your Group array , then you'll need to select the HTML content you'll need.
After that You'll want to use some array methods to take the selected HTML content the way you want it inside your Group object.
Please check documentation of .map() , .forEach() , spread operators , etc to check examples

Comment: Thank you for your comments - sorry about the low quality of the original post. After many edits, I think it should now be clearer with what I have, and what I want. @rossijonas I will check those out, thanks.

Comment: @Josh no worries! You know, there's a nice free course that can give you more knowledge of some js methods and objects/arrays operations. I'ts Javascript30 from WesBos. Worth a look! ✌️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `reduce()` to return object and `Array.from` to turn jQuery objects to array of objects so you can use `reduce` method on it.

```js
// Select direct div children of body, make an array from them and use reduce on it
const data = Array.from($('body > div')).reduce(function(r, e) {
  // Add property for each div / object in array where key is id and value will be another object from array of children of current div 
  r.groups[e.id] = Array.from($(e).children())
    .reduce(function(acc, el, i, arr) {
      // Here we are looping each element in div and if (i % 2 == 0) that means its property so we will use it for key and the next one will be used for value
      if (i % 2 == 0) acc[el.textContent] = arr[i + 1].textContent
      // return accumulator
      return acc
    }, {})
  // return accumulator
  return r;
  // Accumulator of first reduce is object with groups property
}, {groups: {}})

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="england">
  <div class="property">health</div>
  <div class="count">3</div>
  <div class="property">education</div>
  <div class="count">1</div>
  <div class="property">entertainment</div>
  <div class="count">12</div>
</div>
<div id="scotland">
  <div class="property">geography</div>
  <div class="count">5</div>
  <div class="property">history</div>
  <div class="count">2</div>
</div>
<div id="wales">
  <div class="property">illustration</div>
  <div class="count">4</div>
  <div class="property">business</div>
  <div class="count">6</div>
  <div class="property">fashion</div>
  <div class="count">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks Nenad, that looks like it works. There's a lot there that I don't recognise (and therefore don't understand). Could you edit with some explanation of what each line is doing? That would be really appreciated!

Comment: Just realised I never thanked you for adding in the comments - really appreciated it :)